# Interval between tests in pytest

Tags: sleep, pytest, intervals

Is there a common practice to add interval between tests in pytest? Currently integration tests fail but work fine if running the tests individually.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use autouse fixtures in pytest to automatically sleep in between test cases:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def slow_down_tests():
    yield
    time.sleep(1)
```

This fixture will automatically be used for all test cases and will yield execution to a test case so it can run normally, but when the test finishes, the execution will come back to this fixture and the sleep will be run.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a teardown in a module **for every function of the module**:

```py
import time
def teardown_function(function):   # the function parameter is optional
    time.sleep(3)
```

---

If you want a teardown in a class **for every method of the class**, you've two options.

1. In this you can't access the invoked method:

```py
class TestClass:
    def teardown(self):
        time.sleep(1)
```

2. If you need to access it:

```py
class TestClass:
    def teardown_method(self, method):
        print(method)
        time.sleep(1)
```

---

If you want a teardown that will be **invoked once after a class**:

```py
@classmethod
def teardown_class(cls):
    print(cls)
    time.sleep(2)
```

> All of this methods works in the same way for setups. You can see [the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/xunit_setup.html#method-and-function-level-setup-teardown). Use [fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture) for more complex implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert `time.sleep(1)` in the teardown method of each test, i.e:

```
class TestClass:
    def setup(self):
        pass

    def teardown(self):
        time.sleep(1) # sleep for 1 second
```